# FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1).../

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, post, mysql-connector

```
 Future<void> insert()async{
   try{
     if( _formKey.currentState!.validate()){
       String Url="http://10.0.2.2/class/insert.php";
       var res=await http.post(Uri.parse(Url),body: {
         "title":_titlecontroller.text.toString(),
         "desc":_descriptioncontroller.text.toString(),
         "desc1":_description1controller.text.toString(),
         "desc2":_description2controller.text.toString(),
         "desc3":_description3controller.text.toString(),
         "code":_codecontroller.text.toString(),
         "code1":_code1controller.text.toString(),
         "code2":_code2controller.text.toString(),
       });
       var response=jsonDecode(res.body);

       if (response["success"]==true) {
         print("success");
       } else {
         print("some issue");
       }
     }
     else{
       Utils.showErrorMessage("Enter all fields", context);
     }
   }
   catch(e){
     Utils.showErrorMessage("$e", context);
     print(e);
   }


  }
```

when i call this function this error happened

```
I/flutter (13861): FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
I/flutter (13861): <br />
I/flutter (13861): ^
```

Comment: Dear Muhammad, first of all please check your request by postman or anything else and please try printing the response body before calling jsonDecode to see if the response is actually empty or invalid

Comment: I am trying to insert data backend-->php

Comment: I want insert data in mysql but i am getting above error        and for response it is unable to check try block .

Comment: Your response is HTML, not JSON.  You also should always check the status code of the response before assuming anything about the response body.

Comment: @jamesdlin how i can solve??

Comment: @MuhammadZohaib please check your endpoint once with postman or another else, If you confirm that the server is returning HTML instead of JSON, then you should check the server-side code to ensure that it is returning the expected JSON response. You may need to modify the server-side code to fix this issue.

Comment: @MuhammadZohaib, hey my friend, did you solve your problem or did you see the answer?

Answer (score 0):

In comments, I told you that please first check your endpoint once with postman or another else to see that do you have problem with connecting to server or not.
and you can update your code to this to ensure that you have problem with your code or not:

```
String Url="http://10.0.2.2/class/insert.php";
var headers = <String, String>{'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
var res = await http.post(Uri.parse(Url), headers: headers, body:{...});

if (res.statusCode == 200) {
  if (res.headers['content-type'] == 'application/json') {
    var response = jsonDecode(res.body);
    if (response["success"] == true) {
      print("success");
    } else {
      print("some issue");
    }
  } else {
    throw FormatException('Invalid content-type: ${res.headers['content-type']}');
  }
} else {
  throw Exception('Failed to load data');
}
```

and let me know what happend.

happy coding...

Comment: it through this Invalid content-type: ${res.headers['content-type']}

Comment: please print res.headers['content-type'] and tell me what is the response and please please please check the api in postman first because it might have the server response problem